# How to invoke dll calls from Spring boot maven web project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dll, java-native-interface, embedded-jetty

I have Springboot maven project to develop web application with embedded jetty server. The targeted packaging is jar and on execution it needs to listen on localhost.The web application works as expected and I,m able to call the Rest APIs I exposed with `RestController`.

Now I need to integrate a SDK (a standalone jar) and consume the capabilities which the jar exposes.

The jar is a wrapper for a DLL. In order to use it the jar and the DLL should be in same directory. It uses JNI to expose the functionalities of the DLL.
How can i integrate this SDK (jar with dll) into my maven-springboot project. The SDK is output of a normal java project (which does not use maven)?
Also is there any restrictions in invoking a dll (using `System.load()`) from the embedded server? Will there be any linkage errors?

Also is it possible to pack everything in a single executable jar (the depended jar and dll)?

Answer (score 1):

> Also is it possible to pack everything in a single executable jar (the depended jar and dll)?

No, any library (the DLL) must be on the filesystem and loaded as it would by the OS.   You cannot hide it within a JAR file.

As for the `System.load()`, do not use or depend on relative paths. You have basically two options.

1. Use a fully qualified filesystem path reference.

```java
try {
    System.load("C:/projects/masterpo/grasshopper.dll");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    throw new ServletException("Unable to load library");
}
```

2. Use the `java.library.path` system property on JVM startup.

   This would require you to setup the `java.library.path` when the JVM starts to something valid pointing to the directory `C:/projects/masterpo/`.  (this could be an installation step).  But then you can simply use ...

```java
try {
    System.load("grasshopper");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
    throw new ServletException("Unable to load library");
}
```

In regard to the use of `System.load()`, consider using [`Runtime.getRuntime().load(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#load-java.lang.String-) instead.

Comment: I followed the first approach; I kept the dll in same directory, read the location with `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()` and then load the dll file.